# Check when some divs are dropped by a same img

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code about drag and drop in html5:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
ev.preventDefault();
}


</script>

<table width="75" height="75" border="1">
<tr>
<td><div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
<td><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
<td><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<img id="x" src="X.png" draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />
<img id="y" src="y.png" draggable="true" 
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="75" height="75" />
```

Where I stuck is, I'm trying to detect when div1, div2 and div3 are all dropped by either all 'x.png' or all 'y.png', it gives some response (like alert). But after long time searching for solution I still have no idea now really. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why don't you add an a data-img attr on the div when it is dropped, to contain the filename of the image, as you suggested.

Then when dropping, you check if the data-img attr and the filename of the image are the same. If they are then send an alert.

Comment: I can't do that.. actually I thought for that but I have another img which could be drag and drop into the same div so that I might not be able to build a 1:1 relationship by using data-img.... sry about lacking explanation, I'll edit.